# value function referencing another cell

Tags: google-sheets

I've been searching and can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I have a cell that has a function in it that returns a string that returns a value like 2/2. I'm trying to conditionally format it based on the decimal that fraction makes.

If I use this function:

```
=VALUE(2/2)
```

Google sheets correctly interprets this as 1. However, if the 2/2 is sitting in Cell A1, and I pass the cell as:

```
=VALUE(A1)
```

I get the returned value of 42404, which I'm assuming is it interpreting the string and returning an integer, so I also tried:

```
=VALUE(INDIRECT("A1"))
```

which gives me the same value of 42404.

How can I pass the contents of the cell (i.e. 2/2) instead of the reference to the cell?  Thanks, this has been

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the Date Value when referencing the data from the cell.  That date being 2/2/2016.

When you use `=VALUE(2/2)` you are actually dividing 2 by 2 THEN returning the value.  You may as well have entered `=VALUE(1)`.  If you change it to `=VALUE("2/2")` you get 42404 as well.  So even if you set the cell's formatting to text you will get 42404.

If the items in the cell will always have a consistent format we may be able to parse it to a formula which will get the results you are looking for.

Comment: That makes sense. The formula I have to calculate the 2/2 counts a bunch of cells then puts a "/" then counts a bunch of other cells. I can recreate a similar formula and calculate the fraction that way, but I was trying not to do double the work.

Comment: Yes, you can use the QUOTIENT(dividend, divisor) and put your counts in for the 2 parts.  So you have 2 options:  Break your counts into 2 cells and use a third to show the division, or place the formulas in the QUOTIENT() formula.  I would go with using 3 cells but it is a function of how you want to display the data in the end.